# How to add custom features to zurb's Foundation drop-downs?

Tags: css, html, sass, zurb-foundation

As shown in the image bellow, Foundation adds a grey triangle pointing down as its icon for a drop-down area. The problem is: how do I customize it? I want to turn it white.

[image]

I've tried to find it using both Firebug and Chrome dev tools to no avail. I just can't find what codes that triangle and how to customize it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrow is created in line 576 of presentation.css, specifically the following lines:

```
border: solid 5px; 
border-color: #e6e6e6 transparent transparent transparent;
```

I've never seen this technique for creating a triangle, but it's explained quite nicely [here](http://jonrohan.me/guide/css/creating-triangles-in-css/).